# LaTeX Never Finishes Compiling After Renewing a Command

Tags: amsmath, environments, compiling, vector, renewcommand

I have a document that frequently uses the `\vec` command from the amsmath package. I decided I wanted to make all the vectors boldfaced, so I added the following `\renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\vec{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

Now when I try to compile the document (using Texmaker), it says, 'Process started,' indefinitely; no errors appear. At first I thought that it might be caused by the document having to update all the existing `\vec` commands already, but I don't believe that would cause compile times like this (its been trying to compile for several minutes now)

If I remove the `\renewcommand` then it compiles near instantaneously.

Does anybody know what may be causing this?

Edit: I just tried using the following \newcommand

```
\newcommand{\vecbf}[1]{\vec{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

and then I replaced all existing `\vec` commands with `\vecbf`. This solution works and compiles very quickly. I can continue using this solution, but I don't understand why renew command doesn't work.

Edit 2: I think I know why `\renewcommand` doesn't work in the way I used it, but I'm not positive. I believe it is because I'm using the command I'm renewing in the renewed definition, causing a sort of infinite loop.

Comment: `\let\oldvec\vec\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\oldvec{\mathbf{#1}}}`.

Comment: @user240002 This solution works perfectly. Thank you!